# Example of a function with bounded second derivative but non-quadratic

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Bbb R^d \to [0, \infty)$ be such that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$, twice differentiable and 
$$|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}| < C$$ for all $i.j$. I want to know an example of such a $f$ which is not a quadratic function.

Comment: A (positive) constant function? The zero function? (Maybe you want an additional restriction.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I forgot to add one important condition $f(x) \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Any sum of sines and/or cosines should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\,\sqrt {1+|x|^2}?$

Comment: I forgot to add one important condition $f(x) \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$.